# HTTP server not to support persistent connections

Tags: standards-compliance, httpserver, http-1.1

is it possible for an HTTP/1.1 server not to support persistent connections and still be HTTP-compliant?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can read the specification here.

[HTTP 1.1 implementations SHOULD implement persistent connections.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1)

SHOULD means that  there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore persistent connections, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

Answer (score -1):

You should implement persistent connections for HTTP/1.1

> A significant difference between HTTP/1.1 and earlier versions of HTTP is that persistent connections are the default behavior of any HTTP connection. That is, unless otherwise indicated, the client SHOULD assume that the server will maintain a persistent connection, even after error responses from the server.

The optionality of this is really intended for HTTP clients.

Source: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1

Comment: -1 It says 'SHOULD' clearly in the specification you reference. The reference also clearly defines the meaning of 'SHOULD' 'MUST' etc. Therefore any implementation that ignored them would be unusual but it would still be compliant...

Comment: I believed that the client could opt not to have a persistent connection by setting the appropriate header, not that the server could not support it at all.

Comment: yea both those are true - the client doesn't have to send it and the server is free to ignore it.